# inspecting buffer pool content using V$BH view appears unreliable

Tags: oracle, database-administration, oracle19c

I executed this query on Oracle 19c where the partitioned table GRID_LTA has been assigned to KEEP POOL buffer and any segment related name has prefix GRID_LTA as well as primary key and indexes:

```
SQL> set timing on

SQL> set autotrace on

SQL> SELECT count(distinct t.AVG)  n  FROM MY_SCHEMA.GRID_LTA t;

N

--------------------------------------

                                  308

Elapsed: 00:00:01.80

Execution Plan

----------------------------------------------------------

Plan hash value: 3595206837

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

| Id | Operation             | Name            | Rows  | Bytes| (%CPU)| Time     | Pstart| Pstop |

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

|  0 | SELECT STATEMENT     |                        |    1 |   13 |104K (1)| 00:00:05 |       |       |

|  1 | SORT AGGREGATE       |                        |    1 |   13 |            |          |       |       |

|  2 |  VIEW                | VW_DAG_0  |  308 |4004|104K (1)| 00:00:05 |       |       |

|  3 |   HASH GROUP BY      |                        |  308 | 1232| 104K (1)| 00:00:05 |       |       |

|  4 |    PARTITION LIST ALL |                        | 4979K|  18M| 104K (1)| 00:00:05 |    1 |    22 |

|  5 |     TABLE ACCESS FULL| GRID_LTA      | 4979K|  18M| 104K (1)| 00:00:05 |    1 |    22 |

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Statistics

----------------------------------------------------------

         3 recursive calls

         0 db block gets

    **376769 consistent gets
         0 physical reads**

         0 redo size

       581 bytes sent via SQL*Net to client

       588 bytes received via SQL*Net from client

         2 SQL*Net roundtrips to/from client

         0 sorts (memory)

         0 sorts (disk)

         1 rows processed
```

After ten second I submitted this query to inspect the content of the V$BH view:

```
select  o.OWNER,o.object_name, count(distinct block#) k1, count(block#) k2

from    sys.dba_objects o, SYS.V_$BH b

where   b.OBJD = o.OBJECT_ID

and     b.status != 'free'

and     o.owner = 'MY_SCHEMA'

and     instr(o.object_name,'GRID_LTA') > 0

group by o.OWNER,o.object_name;


Statistics

----------------------------------------------------------

        27 recursive calls

         0 db block gets

      1764 consistent gets

         0 physical reads

         0 redo size

       574 bytes sent via SQL*Net to client

       577 bytes received via SQL*Net from client

         1 SQL*Net roundtrips to/from client

         0 sorts (memory)

         0 sorts (disk)

         **0 rows processed**
```

Now it appears the table has completely been read from buffer pool but inspecting buffer pool there isn't any block.

Did I something wrong or is there a possibile explanation ?

How is it possible inspecting the buffer pool in reliable way ?

Answer (score 0):

just solved, using data_object_id instead object_id how I've seen abroad in some examples.